# How to read a value from a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I have the following XML File,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MainClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Items>
    <Settings xsi:type="FileModel">
      <Name>FileRepository</Name>
      <IsActive>true</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
    <Settings xsi:type="ServerModel">
      <Name>DelRep</Name>
      <IsActive>false</IsActive>
      <IsHidden>false</IsHidden>
    </Settings>
  </Items>
  <DirectoryPath>D:\MainFolder</DirectoryPath>
</MainClass>
```

This XML File stored above in a string as `string wholeContent = File.ReadAllText(this.FilePath);`

where this FilePath has a valid path to the location of the file .

the wholeContent stores the entire XML which I later use but now I have the necessity to obtain the path stores as a string within the `<DirectoryPath>` . Is there a way I can do this using wholeContent  or what would be the appropriate approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not to load the XML document as string, use the types provided by .NET, such as XDocument.

Accessing the elements and their values gets very easy that way:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(this.FilePath);
var element = document.Root.Elements().Single(x => x.Name == "DirectoryPath");
var directoryPath = element.Value;
```